# Showing Subcategory Name/Link Instead of Parent Category

Tags: php, categories

right now this code is showing an article's subcategories if it has one. But it's also showing the parent category too (so both the parent category and child categories show up simultaneously). Is there a way to modify this code so that if an article is in a subcategory, it only shows those subcategories and hides the parent category? And if it's only in a parent category, it shows the parent category? Thank you!

```
    <?php $category_separator = "";
foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
     $parentcat = $childcat->term_id;
     if( $parentcat != 0 ) echo '<span class="' . get_cat_name($parentcat) .'"><a href="' . get_category_link($parentcat) . '">' .get_cat_name($parentcat) .'</a></span>';
     else echo '' . $category_separator . '<span class="'. $childcat->cat_name .'"><a href="' . get_category_link($childcat) .'">' . $childcat->cat_name . '</a></span>';
    $category_separator = " / ";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you can't know the order of categories returned by `get_the_category`, I suggest to loop through the categories and fill two arrays, one for parent and one for children.
After that if the parents array is empty showing the children, otherwise show the parents:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
if ( ! empty($categories) ) {
  $parents = array();
  $children = array();
  foreach( get_the_category() as $cat ) {
    if ( $cat->parent == 0 ) {
      $parents[] = $cat;
    } else {
      $children[] = $cat;
    }
  }
  $toshow = ! empty($children) ? $children : $parents;
  $sep = '';
  if ( ! empty($toshow) ) { foreach( $toshow as $cat ) {
    echo $sep;
    echo '<span class="' . $cat->name .'">';
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($cat->term_id) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a></span>';
    $sep = ' / ';
  } }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me...

Comment: Thank you, but now it seems to be showing only the parent category and not the child category. ^_^;; Posts that are in a parent category show those categories, but if it's in a child category of a parent category, only the parent category shows.

Comment: Oh, no, I want it so that if a post has child categories to only show those child categories and not the parent categories.

Comment: @user1445975 Now if a post has parent + children categories show only children categories. If a post has only children categories show children categories. If a post has only parent categories show parent categories.